# Web root inside a symlink - How to redirect with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I like to rewrite urls and redirect them to inside a symlink.
I googled almost the whole net but every comment what I found are writes about symlinks inside a web folder.
But in my case all the files are inside a symlinked folder also with the htaccess file.
But the redirect doesnt work. I think it happened because of the symlink.

So, my folder structure looks like:

```
    www.domain.com
       ~symlink
          dir1
          dir2
         .htaccess
         index.php
```

Does somebody have a good idea to solve this redirection?
thx

Comment: Kinda hard to say anything useful with the .htaccess file. Please post the .htaccess as well.

Comment: THX scallio. The problem solved. There was something of a config mistake in apache.